# how to add a circle with tooltip to a d3 chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm new to D3 and trying to figure out how to add a circle to the chart with a tooltip attached.  I want to be able to apply notes to the chart at different dates and prices.  The note text should popup in the tooltip.

Here is an [example](http://www.tekknow.net/Screener/index-chart.html) I'm working on.  I want a circle to appear on x = March 1 at a y price = 1000.

I added a div.tooltip in the css like this:

```
div.tooltip {   
    position: absolute;         
    text-align: center;         
    width: 60px;                    
    height: 28px;                   
    padding: 2px;               
    font: 12px sans-serif;      
    background: lightsteelblue; 
    border: 0px;        
    border-radius: 8px;         
    pointer-events: none;           
}
```

In the main function that draws the chart I added a call to showNotes(), like this:

```
showNotes(x,y)
```

where x and y are defined:

```
var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeBands([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .rangeRound([height, 0]);
```

I created one note in an array like this:

```
var timeStamp = new Date("March 1, 2016");
var notes = [{"TIMESTAMP":timeStamp,"PRICE":1000.0,"NOTE":"Hello World!"}];
```

Then the function showNotes(x,y) is:

```
function showNotes(x,y) {
// Define the div for the tooltip
var div = d3.select("body").append("div")   
    .attr("class", "tooltip")               
    .style("opacity", 0);

d3.select("#chart1").selectAll("note")  
    .data(notes)            
    .enter().append("circle")                               
    .attr("r", 50)      
    .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.TIMESTAMP); })      
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.PRICE); })     
    .on("mouseover", function(d) {      
        div.transition()        
            .duration(200)      
            .style("opacity", .9);      
        div .html(d.NOTE)   
            .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")     
            .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");    
        })                  
    .on("mouseout", function(d) {       
        div.transition()        
            .duration(500)      
            .style("opacity", 0);   
    });
}
```

A circle is supposed to appear on the chart at x=March 1, 2016, y=1000.0.  And when I hover over it, the note "Hello World" is supposed to show.  But the circle doesn't even show up.  There are no errors in the chrome console.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: the circle is never positioned correct in x in all time scales

Comment: You're right.  The 1M, 1Y, and 2Y the circle does not land on the right date, even though Mar 1, 2016 stays within the range.  Any idea why?

Comment: if you draw a smaller circle you see it is also incorrect for 3M, reason x is an ordinal scale not a linear-time-scale

Comment: Do you have suggestion for how to change code to make it land on the right date, regardless of time scale?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The selector `d3.select("#chart1")` is incorrect as it returns a position above the SVG element. You want to select the elements under the SVG element (the `g` elements) so that the `note` elements you insert become children of the `SVG` element.

Changing the selector to `d3.select("#chart1 svg g")` solves the problem and shows the circle and tooltip correctly.

Comment: Thank you.  I was so close!